# Does Sqoop support extracting data from partitioned oracle table

Tags: sqoop

I have a very large oracle table which is a partitioned table, I would ask whether or how Sqoop supports to do split based on oracle partitions, eg, one mapper to do import from one oracle partition.

Comment: Could someone help on this problem? Thanks

Comment: No Sqoop developer on stackoverflow？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sqoop supports import from oracle partitioned table. [Here](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_match_hadoop_files_to_oracle_table_partitions) is the documentation.

Syntax is somthing like this

```
sqoop import \
-Doraoop.disabled=false \
-Doraoop.import.partitions='"PARTITION-NAME","PARTITION-NAME1","PARTITION-NAME2",' \
--connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:15XX:SCHEMA_NAME \
--username user \
--password password \
--table SCHEMA.TABLE_NAME \
--target-dir /HDFS/PATH/ \
-m 1
```

Single mapper will be assigned to each partition that will write data to HDFS simultaneously.

Make sure you have dynamic partitions property enabled and number of partitions property value is also higher than the partitions existing in oracle when you create Hive table.

Comment: Thanks @shahab-niaz. From your description, it sounds that different oracle partiton will write to different hive partition dynamically one by one, perhaps using oracle's partition name as hive's partition name. What if I want to write data from all oracle partitions to write to one single Hive partition(eg, write all the data to the hive's day='$today' partition)

Comment: For that I do not think sqoop has that option, what I can suggest is that you initially create a table with partitions in Hive/Hdfs using sqoop then create a new table with your desired partition that could be a date, your query for creating a new table would look something like this, insert into {DB}.{NEW_TABLE}  select *,current_date from {DB}.{SQOOP_IMPORTED_TABLE}

Comment: sure, thanks @shahab-niaz for the detailed instruction.

Comment: How do you set `number of partitions` and `dynamic partitions` @ShahabNiaz?